# Does aperiodicity needed for ergodic theorem to hold true?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, ergodic-theory

Given a irreducible and positive recurrent countable state Markov Chain with unique stationary distribution $\pi$, is the following true

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i \to \sum j \pi_j$$

Or, to claim the above aperiodicity is also needed

What about when the process has uncountable state space ?

Comment: Wouldn't that follow solely from possessing a stable distribution ?

Comment: @Bey: I also think so. But, seen in a paper that aperiodicity is also needed.

Comment: Can you reference the paper?

Comment: @Bey:http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~sudiptob/pubh8429/MarkovChains12.pdf. Check the last Corollary.

Comment: Since your state space is continuous, I think this is requried.

Comment: See here:http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vigoda/MCMC_Course/MC-basics.pdf it's required even in finite mc's since there must be a $t: P^t(x,y)>0 \forall x,y\in \Omega$

Comment: @Bey: Sorry, I don't see the theorem I mentioned in my post (time average = space average) in the article.

Comment: No...it mentions conditions for being ergodic which implies time avg = space average (by def. of ergodic)

Comment: @Bey: I did not understand your argument. I want to know whether the statement mentioned above can be proved without aperiodicity assumption.

Answer (score 0):

No, aperiodicity is not needed, only irreducibility (which is the statement that for all $x,y$ there exists an $n$ such that $P^n(x,y)>0$). In fact, even for a periodic or cyclic chain you get the result, that the Cesaro average of $P^n$ converges to a matrix in which every row equals $\pi$. Your result then follows from this.

The proof is based on the fact that for a period $d$, you can interpret $P^d$ as the transition matrix of a Markov chain with $d$ separate ergodic sets that are all aperiodic. Hence, $P^{kd+l}$, for $l\in\{0,...,d-1\}$, has $d$ converging subsequences. If a sequence has converging subsequences, it is Cesaro summable.

For the details I can recommend Theorem 5.1.4 in Kemeny and Snell's "Finite Markov Chains".